# rendering components in Aurelia w/o the intermediate DOM Node

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, aurelia

Is it possible to render custom element templates directly in Aurelia without the additional custom element wrapper node?

For example, say, I have a component like such:

```js
// -- component.js
export class UiComponent {}

// -- component.html
<template>
    <div class="ui-component">
        { ... some content ... }
    </div>
</template>
```

... and I have a wrapper component rendering ui-component like such:

```js
// -- wrapper.js
export class UiWrapper {}

// -- wrapper.html
<template>
    <require from="/path/to/component.js"></require>

    <div class="ui-wrapper">
        <ui-component></ui-component>
    </div>
</template>
```

This would result in the DOM tree looking something like such:

```html
<ui-wrapper>
    <div class="ui-wrapper">
        <ui-component>
            <div class="ui-component">
                { ... some content ... }
            </div>
        </ui-component>
    </div>
</ui-wrapper>
```

---

The question: is it possible to render the DOM without the extra markup noise that custom elements generate?

```html
<div class="ui-wrapper">
    <div class="ui-component">
        { ... some content ... }
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Why I want this:

- I don't like styling the custom element wrappers themselves (i.e., the `<ui-component>` or the `<ui-wrapper>`. I believe it is markup noise as I cannot manipulate its classes, nor can I attach event handlers directly on it.
- On elements that use `repeat.for`, I cannot simply use `:last-child` css selectors. I would have to add yet another class check using `${ $last ? 'is-last-child' : '' }`, which again, is markup noise.
- These intermediate elements break the margin of whatever is inside it. Instead of acting like real margins (which collapse together when margins "collide"), my margins get doubled in between components because the custom element node wraps the margin-ed element in a block container without any margin.

---

I hope that all made sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
    // -- component.js
    import {containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

    @containerless
    export class UiComponent {}
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910887/7523242)

Comment: woah, I didn't know that existed! Thanks! I didn't know what exact terms to look for so my searches yielded no similar results.